# How to connect two SKNodes with path?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two SpriteKit nodes and I want to connect them with CGPath. While moving Nodes path should stay attached to the nodes. I can create manager which tracks node movement and redraw lines each time but I just would like to know if there is any functionality in Swift which supports this behavior out of the box without writing tracker code?

Comment: You can use a skshapenode to attach both nodes. Then add constraints. It should be straightforward.

Comment: @E.Coms but in this case when I move node in one end of path the other node on the other end will also move right? What I am trying to do is to build graph framework where I can put nodes and connect them with edges and will be able to move nodes around doing so edges should follow node to which it is attached but the other end of edge should stay still since I dont move other end

Comment: You can use two constraints. one for each end.  You may start from one line as path. Then you can upgrade the line to other complicated edges when you feel comfortable using SKConstraint